# Wipe clean all the packages and drivers related to cuda and nvidia and start fresh

Tags: drivers, apt, 20.04, nvidia, cuda

I'm using an old HP laptop(about 6 years old). It does not support tensorflow above 2.2 due to some compute capability and micro-architecture issues. With some tricks I installed tf2.2.0 on my ubuntu 20.04. However, after a year or so of normal working, I did something which I don't remember, but the cuda and nvidia setup got malfunctioned. I tried to reinstalled nvcc and other cuda tools, libraries and drivers but now I'm getting lots of error and unable to even completely remove it. I tried `sudo apt remove --purge cuda*` which returned `E: Unable to locate package cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-1-local-10.1.243-418.87.00_1.0-1_amd64.deb`. I also did `sudo apt remove --purge cuda` & `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*` (these ran without any error). However, I when I typed `whereis` for both cuda and nvidia, i got addresses. After all this I'm too much tired (have spent 2 weeks or so on this). I just want to completely wipe everything related to graphic drivers, nvidia and cuda. So that I can start fresh. Please suggest what can I do

Comment: 1) Your unquoted `*` (`sudo apt remove --purge cuda*`) risks matching files in the current directory. Try`sudo apt remove --purge 'cuda*'`. 2) All the packages you install via the packaging system are logged in `/var/log/apt/`.

Comment: after doing what you suggested, I checked ```whereis cuda``` and it still shows ```/usr/lib/cuda     /usr/local/cuda```